accessing TFrame objects in TListBox items
I have a TFrame with a TNumberBox field that is being inserted several times inside a TListBox in Firemonkey. How do I access the value of this object when looping through the items?
Frame:
type
  TfrmTipoOrc = class(TFrame)
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    edValor: TNumberBox;
  end;

Form:
type
  TfrmOrcamento = class(TForm)
    btnSalvar: TSpeedButton;
    listaOrcamento: TListBox;
    procedure btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TfrmOrcamento.btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    i: Integer; 
    vValor: Double;
begin    
    for i := 0 to Pred(listaOrcamento.Count) do
        begin
            // vValor := vValor + TfrmTipoOrc.edValor.Value;
            // How to access the frame's TfrmTipoOrc.edValor instance?
        end;
end;


One has to use .Components of a each .ListItem:
procedure TfrmOrcamento.btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    i: Integer; 
    vValor: Double;
begin    
    for i := 0 to Pred(listaOrcamento.Count) do
        begin
              vValor := vValor+
              TfrmTipoOrc(listaOrcamento.ListItems[i].Components[0]).edValor.Value;
        end;
end;

